# jQuery $.get() adding slashes not saving edits even after slashes removed

Tags: php, jquery

I have created a simple CSS editing/optimizing system in a WordPress plugin. Basically, the CSS files are stored in a folder. They are accessed to edit though a selection box using jQuery.

**HTML**

```
# edit stylesheet
        echo '<div id="editStyles" class="s8w-hide">';
            echo '<h2>Edit a Stylesheet</h2>';
            echo '<form action="" method="post">';
            
                # file name
                echo '<div class="s8w-row">';
                    echo '<div class="s8w-col_12">';                    
                        echo '<select id="getStylesheeteEdit" name="filename" class="s8w-expand">';
                            echo '<option value="">Select Stylesheet to Edit</option>';
                            foreach(glob(S8W_CSS_GEN . 'common/*.css') as $file) {
                            $filename = basename($file);
                                echo '<option value="'.$filename.'">'.$filename.'</option>';
                            }                           
                        echo '</select>';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
                
                # styles
                echo '<div class="s8w-row">';
                    echo '<div class="s8w-col_12">';
                        echo '<textarea id="showEditStyles" name="styles" class="s8w-expand" style="height: 350px;"></textarea>';       
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';

                echo '<div class="s8w-row">';
                    echo '<div class="s8w-col_12 s8w-center">';                 
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="edit_stylesheet" class="s8w navy tiny-radius" value="Edit this Stylesheet">';
                    echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';

            echo '</form>';
```

**jQuery**
This jQuery added slashes so I added the commented out line but it did not remove them.

```
/* GET STYLESHEET TO EDIT 
    ----------------------------------------------------- */
    $( "#getStylesheeteEdit" ).change(function() {
        var which = $(this).val();
        var file = 'https://s8w.org/wp-content/plugins/IDCCST/css/generator/common/' + which;
        $.get(file, function(data) {
            //data.replace('\\','');
            $('#showEditStyles').val(data);
            
        });
    });
```

**parsing php**
I added stripslashes here which did remove the slashes.

```
/* EDIT STYLESHEET
    --------------------------------------------------------- */
    if(array_key_exists('edit_stylesheet',$_POST)){
        
        $filename = $_POST['filename'];
        $styles = stripslashes($_POST['styles']);
        
        # update styles
        file_put_contents(S8W_CSS_GEN  . 'common/'.$filename, $styles); 
        
        # parse stylesheets
        $msg = 'The stylesheet: '.$filename.' and the S8W Stylesheet have been updated.';
        parseStyles($msg);
    }
```

**parseStyles($msg);** minimizes and writes single style sheet.

```
<?php

    function parseStyles($msg){
        
        /* admin styles
        -------------------------------------- */
        foreach(glob(S8W_CSS_GEN . 'admin/*.css') as $file) {
            
            $admin_code .= file_get_contents($file);
            
            $prep_styles = file_get_contents($file);        
            $prep_styles = str_replace("/*","~",$prep_styles);
            $prep_styles = str_replace("*/","~",$prep_styles);      
                preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $prep_styles, $match);
                foreach($match[1] as $val) {
                    $this_comment = '~'.$val.'~'; 
                    $prep_styles = str_replace($this_comment,"",$prep_styles);      
                }
            //$prep_styles = str_replace('\"','"',$prep_styles);                
            $prep_styles = str_replace("\r","",$prep_styles);
            $prep_styles = str_replace("\n","",$prep_styles);
            $prep_styles = str_replace("\t","",$prep_styles);       
            $admin_styles .= $prep_styles;
            
        }
        
        /* common styles
        -------------------------------------- */
        foreach(glob(S8W_CSS_GEN . 'common/*.css') as $file) {
            
            $common_code .= file_get_contents($file);
            
            $prep_styles = file_get_contents($file);        
            $prep_styles = str_replace("/*","~",$prep_styles);
            $prep_styles = str_replace("*/","~",$prep_styles);      
                preg_match_all("'~(.*?)~'si", $prep_styles, $match);
                foreach($match[1] as $val) {
                    $this_comment = '~'.$val.'~'; 
                    $prep_styles = str_replace($this_comment,"",$prep_styles);      
                }
            //$prep_styles = str_replace('\"','"',$prep_styles);                
            $prep_styles = str_replace("\r","",$prep_styles);
            $prep_styles = str_replace("\n","",$prep_styles);
            $prep_styles = str_replace("\t","",$prep_styles);       
            $common_styles .= $prep_styles;
            
        }
        
        # write admin styles
        $admin_styles = $common_styles.$admin_styles;       
        file_put_contents(S8W_CSS . 's8w-admin-styles.css', $admin_styles);
        
        # write admin styles
        $admin_readable = $common_code.$admin_code;     
        file_put_contents(S8W_CSS_GEN . 'readable-admin.css', $admin_readable);
        
        $common_styles = $common_styles;
        # write admin styles
        file_put_contents(S8W_CSS . 's8w-styles.css', $common_styles);
        
        # write admin styles
        $common_readable = $common_code;        
        file_put_contents(S8W_CSS_GEN . 'readable.css', $common_readable);      

        echo '<Script language="javascript">alert("'.$msg.'");</script>';
        
    }
```

All of this code works great if the styles do not have double quote. The file is called to the editing textarea and parses perfectly and write the minimized file. However, if the styles have double quotes:

**CSS Example with Double Quotes**

```
/*  BUTTONS
------------------------------------------------------------------- */
button.s8w, 
a.button.s8w,
input[type="submit"].s8w,
input[type="button"].s8w {
    position:relative;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    padding:10px 15px;
    line-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow:visible;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-size:16px; 
    text-decoration:none;   
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display:inline-block;
    zoom:1;
    background: #fcfcfc;
    color:#666;
    border:1px solid #cccccc;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

The file will save and be minimized. But when the file is called though jQuery, though the edits are saved to the file, the new edits do not render in the textarea and as a result are lost if the file is saved once again. Hope I was able to explain the problem clearly. Any help or thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: jQuery shouldn't do anything regarding slashes. Try adding content type `'html'` as second argument of `$.get(function(data){/* code*/},'html')`. Is this going through a php ouput buffer that might be doing some escaping before it outputs?

Comment: PHP doesn't add slashes to output.

Comment: Also note that String#replace() only works on first instance if a regex with g flag not used

Comment: @charlietfl I tried `$.get(function(data){/* code*/},'html')` and the file was not called into the textarea for edit. I am not sure what you mean by an output buffer. On the selection of `getStylesheeteEdit` the jQuery gets the file like `file_get_contents()` in  php. This is where the slashes get added if the return has double quotes. If the file does not have quotes everything works. The edits are saved and if the same edited file is selected again the edits show up in the textarea as expected. With quotes the edits are saved but if selected again the edits do not render in the textarea

Comment: So try using stripslashes

Comment: @charlietfl While I still do not understand why my original script did not work, I did find a viable work around... posted it as an answer... thanks for you help.

Comment: It's either happening when you get the file contents or in the file write process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I am still not sure what was happening, the problem was in this jQuery:

```
/* GET STYLESHEET TO EDIT 
    ----------------------------------------------------- */
    $( "#getStylesheeteEdit" ).change(function() {
        var which = $(this).val();
        var file = 'https://s8w.org/wp-content/plugins/IDCCST/css/generator/common/' + which;
        $.get(file, function(data) {
            //data.replace('\\','');
            $('#showEditStyles').val(data);
            
        });
    });
```

When a css file was edited the edits would be saved and parsed through the minimizer php, but the above jQuery would not pick up the edits on the saved file when it was reselected. Have no idea as to why?

I was able to resolve the issue by changing the jQuery to:

```
$( "#getStylesheeteEdit" ).change(function() {
        
        var which = $(this).val();
        var url = 'https://s8w.org/wp-content/plugins/IDCCST/css/generator/get-stylsheet.php';
        var postit = $.post( url, {which:which});    
        postit.done(function( data ) {$('#showEditStyles').val(data);}); 
        
      
    });
```

and adding a php parse file with only one line of code to be able to make use of `file_get_contents()` instead using jQuery to get the contents of the desired css file:

```
<?php

    $file = 'common/'.$_POST['which']; echo file_get_contents($file);
```